# Address in mailbox given [test@gmail.com,test1@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2 laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to send mail to multiple recipients at once but it gives me the above error.even when I am returning allemail variable ...it gives me my email addresses, means variable is also not blank then why this error?? and also my mail goes without body
**View:-**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="m" placeholder="Email" name=email[] 
multiple="multiple">
```

**Controller:-**

```
function sendmail(Request $request)
{
$allemails=$request->get('email');
\Mail::send('emails.contact', array( 'bodyMessage' => $request->get('message'),
'sub' => $request->get('sub')), 
function($message) use ($allemails, $request) {
$message
->from('testadmin@gmail.com')
->subject($request->get('sub')); 
$message->to($allemails);
});
```

**Contact View:-**

```
<p>
{!! $bodyMessage !!}
</p>
```

Comment: Not related, use the "bcc" field instead of the "to" field to not reveal any email adresses to the recipients.

Comment: still it gives same error

Comment: That wasn't a solution, just a suggestion, that's why I said it's not related